# Return value not showing from switch

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

Could someone help me understand why the first function works  while the second one returns undefined? I'm confused as to why the second setup doesn't work, wouldn't it run and return the same add/subtract/multiply/divide function once the case clause is met? Thanks!

Works:

```
//Add function
let add = (a, b) => a + b;

//Subtract function
let subtract = (a, b) => a - b;

//Multiply function
let multiply = (a, b) => a * b;

//Divide function
let divide = (a, b) => a / b;

// Variables to represent number, operator, number
let number1st;
let number2nd;
let operator;

// Operate function
let operate = function (op, a, b) {
    switch (op) {
        case 'add':
            op = add;
            break;
        case 'subtract': 
            op = subtract;
            break;
        case 'multiply':
            op = multiply;
            break;
        case 'divide':
            op = divide;
            break;
    }
    op (a, b);
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
let operate = function (op, a, b) {
     switch (op) {
        case 'add':
            add (a, b);
            break;
        case 'subtract': 
            subtract (a, b);
            break;
        case 'multiply':
            multiply (a, b);
            break;
        case 'divide':
            divide (a, b);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to return the value: `return op(a, b)` in the first version, `return add(a, b)` in the second version.

Comment: I don't see how either version can work. You're not returning anything in either format.

Comment: BTW, don't reuse the `op` variable like that, it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The question is kinda vague, maybe next time try providing some inputs so people can get better insight on your issue.

Furthermore, it's worth noting that both operate() functions don't return any values. As a result, if you call either function, you won't get any output.

I have made the following changes to your code:

```
let number1st = 1;
let number2nd = 1;
let operator = 'add';

let operate = function (op, a, b) {
    switch (op) {
        case 'add':
            op = add;
            break;
        case 'subtract': 
            op = subtract;
            break;
        case 'multiply':
            op = multiply;
            break;
        case 'divide':
            op = divide;
            break;
        default:
            // add something here if you wish
            break;
    }

    return op (a, b); // changed here
}

let result = operate(operator, number1st, number2nd);
console.log(result);

let operate2 = function (op, a, b) {
     switch (op) {
        case 'add':
            return add (a, b); // changed here
        case 'subtract': 
            return subtract (a, b); // changed here
        case 'multiply':
            return multiply (a, b); // changed here
        case 'divide':
            return divide (a, b); // changed here
        default:
            // add something here if you wish
            break;
    }
}

let result2 = operate2(operator, number1st, number2nd);
console.log(result2);
```

In the first case, I have added a `return` statement to the `op(a, b)` call, so that `operate()` will return whatever `op(a, b)` returns.

In the second case, I have removed all `break` statements and replaced them with `return` + the particular operation call (let's say that `op = 'add'`, it will go to the first switch case, compute the value, return it and go back to where the function was initially called). This works similarly to breaking the switch-case.

Just a tip, always think about the default case (i.e., none of the specified cases have occurred).

Let me know if that explanation has helped :)